# Raspberry pi 3 Bluetooth

Tags: android-bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

My Raspberry Pi 3 can connect briefly to my Android mobile, but once I accept the connection on the Raspberry Pi, I get this error:

> GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.Failed: No such file or directory. Try to connect manually.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What operating system and version is installed?

Comment: I have installed RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH PIXEL and kernel version is 4.4. In mobile there is android 6.0(Marshmallow).

Comment: I've tried everything to fix this bug, installe blueman, installing bluez, installing new bluetooth firmware bla bla nothing works. I have 4.4 kernel Raspbian, trying to connect bluetooth speakers!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that from Bluetooth control. Type $bluetoothctl as root then you will end up with Bluetooth shall. There you should type "power on" command. After that you can use "scan on" command to check connection.

Answer (score 0):

to continue from Dinusha's answer, after you scan and find your device's ID (you should also be able to see it's name in parentheses) you'll need to pair with the device by doing

`pair <device ID>`

then connect with the device by doing

`connect <device ID>`

You'll be able to see status of the connection

There are cases where I use a separate bluetooth dongle for connections I don't want dropped

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian Jessie has some issues as far as I know with the Bluetooth module. I'd recommend using bullseye or buster. Also, there are a couple issues regarding the newest kernel. Run the following command to see if your phone which you are willing to connect is listed:

```
sudo bluetoothctl devices
```

If your mobile device is still listed here and not paired on the mobile side, there is your problem. Remove the device using the following command in RPI:

```
sudo bluetoothctl remove <mac-adress-of-device>
```